# It is possible to show that given a statement, to show that is true instead of giving a proof, by showing that a proof is constructable?

Tags: logic, soft-question

I was thinking that we make proofs to show that there is a least one chain of reasoning that starts on p and ends on q. But in math, we dont always have to show something to argue that  exist. Is there a way to show that given an statement $$p \implies q $$ can we argue in some way that from p we can (or cant) construct a chaing of reasoning to get q whitout showing that chain explicitly?
Maybe this is crazy but I was thinking like the tracendental numbers in the way that they cannot be the root of any polynomial, and algebraic numbers can be with such property, i.e., we can construct algebraic numbers with a linear combinations of powers of rational numbers and wonder if can we make an analogous process applied to logic.

Comment: The [completeness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) essentially answers your question. You might also be interested in [intuitionistic lstatemenogic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic), where for example there are statements of the form $p \vee \neg p$ which are neither provable nor refutable. I don't have the time to turn this into a detailed answer but I'm sure someone else will write one very soon.

Comment: To add to Clive's comment without stealing him the chance to answer. The completeness theorem in propositional logic tells you that every tautology is a theorem in that logic and viceversa. There is also a (semantic) completeness theorem for 1st Order Logic and many logics. We can talk about it in class ;)

Comment: That would be very nice! Jajaja